# SSL .Net but for the login session only

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, encryption, password-encryption

I have a client and server I wrote in .Net. it works fine.
The login is using a user name and a password which I encrypt. But the encryption is not good enough (using hard coded encryption key).
So I need replacing the login session to SSL. But as the login session is done, I need the rest of the client-server communication, to be clear TCP. No SSL and no encryption.

Is there a way to that? How?

Instead of SSL, I would prefer to use **NON** hard coded password encryption (I have it now with hard coded key). Any suggestion to that?

Comment: Use a Network credential.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Cant use it as my client has no access to the server net or domain.

Comment: The client only has GUEST privileges which is very limited.  You do NOT want to make your service  run as admin to give clients full access to the system.  So you want so call from the service an executable that gives limited access where needed.